# Why Nuxt is taking styles from other pages?

Tags: css, vue.js, styles, nuxt.js

I have two pages in my Nuxt project:

```
|-pages/
|---index.vue
|---login/
|-----index.vue
```

The `index.vue` inside `pages` has these styles:

```
<style lang="scss">

   html,
   body,
   #__nuxt,
   #__layout,
   main {
      height: 100%;
   }

</style>
```

As you can see, I need my container taking all the screen height, so I need to put that style in all Nuxt containers, for that reason, my styles can't be scoped. Here all is fine, but when I go to `/login` I don't want those styles, but for some reason Nuxt is applying those styles, even if I delete the `<styles>` label inside `pages/login/index.vue`, I don't know why...

In theory, the `pages/index.vue` styles shouldn't be loading if I'm in `/login`

The only solution I found is to put the `scoped` attribute to `page/index.vue` style label, but it doesn't allow me to change the Nuxt's containers height.

Do you know a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you define global CSS styles (by not scoping them), they will indeed be applied to your whole app.
The behavior in `login/index.vue` of your styles having the properties is hence totally fine.

This is called [CSS Cascade](https://wattenberger.com/blog/css-cascade).

If you don't want the behavior being applied to the other pages, you need to either override the properties in the other `.vue` files (which is fine to a certain point) or scope the styles of your root `index.vue`.

You can of course also use [Nuxt layouts](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts#layouts-directory), if you want to apply styles to a specific group of pages.

Also, `height: 100%;` is a pretty generic property. You will not really need it if you use your page flow (by adding regular blocks of HTML one to the other), it will put them accordingly.
For further CSS issues, the usage of the inspector of your browser's devtools is highly recommended and will spare you some struggle!