# Style and script in iframe leak to parent page in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, nuxtjs3

In my `index.vue` page I create an `iframe` element, which is rendering my `iframe.vue` page:

```js
// index.vue

<template>
  <div>This is index page content!</div>
  <iframe src="/iframe"></iframe>
</template>
```

```js
// iframe.vue

<script setup>
  console.log('Hello World inside iframe!');
</script>

<template>This is iframe content.</template>

<style>
* {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that both style and script leak from iframe to parent page (`index.vue`).
All elements are red and I also see message in console log.

How to prevent iframe from applying styles and script to parent page?

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-iframe-leak) on Stackblitz.

[image]

Comment: Could you create an workable example on stackblitz?

Comment: @yunzen Sure, just refresh page a few times: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-iframe-leak

Comment: Your example doesn't show the behavior

Comment: @yunzen It works just fine when loads for the first time. Use the refresh button on the top (near url) and both messages will become red. I am not crazy. Tested in 2 browsers already)

Comment: You need to add `scoped` attribute to the `style` tag: See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css

Comment: @yunzen this wont work because I need to style `body` as well which is not working in `scoped` mode. And I also can't add `scoped` to `script` tag which is leaking too. And I don't think this is the expected behaviour from `iframe` at all... A bug?

Comment: The iframe doesn't leak. It is so that unscoped styles in Vue are made global and don't end at component boundaries.

Comment: @yunzen Then why both messages are not red on the first load if this leak is something to be expected? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573748/why-nuxt-is-taking-styles-from-other-pages

Comment: @EstusFlask I think I will have to stick to `layouts` option but this is really strange for me. I understand the concept of "leaking" global styles and scripts because this all is one big SPA (without page refreshes). But it is iframe, it is not a part of an app...

Comment: This is not about iframe, you can remove <iframe> and it will be the same, this is how nuxt handles pages, they are still vue components, and global styles from comps can leak to a document depending on how they are bundled

Comment: @EstusFlask When I remove `iframe` the text is black. Not the same.

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-iframe-leak-xdv2je , try "open in new tab" if it's not seen in editor window. As long as iframe page is used in the app, it affects it. In case of <iframe> it looks like dev server accumulates the pages in use and adds it to the bundle after the first iframe load

Comment: @EstusFlask This is very bad. Because in my IFrame I import KaTeX styles (for math rendering), PhotoSwipe and more. And it all is polluting parent page and all other pages I use in my app... I guess I will have to compile iframe page separately without Vue environment and then use it...

Comment: Potentially code splitting needs to be configured in nuxt. Also this may differ between dev server and prod. You can additionally take care of style pollution and add unique selector for iframe page, not necessarily through <style scoped>, there are ways to do this depending on your style preprocessor. Generally you'd need a separate vue app for an iframe any way to fully isolate it from main app, it's sad but understandable why this isn't cleanly handled in nuxt the way you did it

Comment: @EstusFlask I ended up creating separate Nuxt app called `preview`, then install it like package dependency in main Nuxt app and copy prerenderered page from `preview` to `public` folder before starting main app. Kind of horrible, but at least it works and provides fully isolated iframe...